# how to pass a variable from html file to javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I need to pass a variable from `page1.html` file to `page2.js`. Must include pure javascript code (without tags like `<script>`).

`page1.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var age = 23;
</script>
<html>
  <!-- some code I need -->
</html>
```

`page2.js`:

```
print(age);
```

Comment: First include the first javascript file in the second js file 
Then just print the value using `print_r(age)`

Comment: How are you navigating between `page1.html` and `page2.js` ? I mean as the 1st page is html and the second js, do you use a library to dynamically load it?

Comment: that's the problem i can't include the  first one (actually the main code is written in java and i am using scriptEngine to read variable from javascipt it workd perfectly but the problem is i need to get variable from html file  and use it i the problem is scriptEngine does not read tages like <script src ="page1.js"> so i need a method to pass an argument from html page to js page using pure js language

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var age = 23;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="your-second_script name"></script>
<html>
  <!-- some code I need -->
</html>
```

It should work
Or else load both javascript externally and load first script which have that variable and then second script which is using that variable

Comment: it's not working  ,  like i said in the comments javascritp engine did not recognise age variable

Comment: Okay then add both scripts externally with script tag in html

Comment: i have added this    var age = 23;    in first js file and saved as first.js                and in second file i'm printing the age variable like this    console.log(age);            and add both scripts in html page like this                                                                     <html>
<head>
<title>ki</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="my"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scriptA.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scriptB.js"></script>
</html>

Answer (score -1):

You can add this code in your `page1.html`:

```
<input value="23" type="text" hidden="hidden" id="myVariable" />
```

and get your variable value in `page2.js` by this code:

```
alert(document.getElementById('myVariable').value)
```

Comment: Scriptengine does not recognise document ! i need pure js code wthout tags or html function